# where does __proto__ property exist in javascript

Tags: javascript

when we create an object of some type like

```
function Creater(a,b){

  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;

}

Creater.prototype.full = function (){ 
            alert(this.a + " " + this.b );
}

prs1 = new Creater('jhon','Doe');
pes1.full();
```

so now pes1 has access to `full` method through prototype chain, every object i create from
`Creater` constructor function has a `__proto__` property through which the look up takes place, but where does this `__proto__` exist on constructor function is it on prototype object of `Creater` function or is it just a property of `Creater` function ? because function is also an object and we can add property/methods to it .

Comment: This is what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: so the '__proto__' property exist on prototype of an object?

Comment: The `__proto__` is a non-standard property that exposes what is otherwise an internal link between objects. So `prs1` has an internal link to the `Creater.prototype` object, so that when you look up a property on `prs1`, and it doesn't exist, the search will automatically continue on the `Creater.prototype` object. The non-standard `__proto__` makes that internal relationship visible.

Comment: ok thanks , what is the difference between these two

Comment: Creater.__proto__ and Creater.prototype.__proto__

Comment: which one is right one?

Comment: @raziqijr: `Creater.prototype` is the object that is assigned to this internal link *when creating the new object*. The `__proto__` is used after the object has been created to observe that relationship between the object and the `Creater.prototype`.